# Elastic Search Interaction of Highlights with Synonym Filter

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

We have an analyzer which includes the synonym filter which is defined as follows:

```
        synonym_filter :
            type : synonym
            synonyms_path : synonyms.txt
            ignore_case : true
            expand : true
            format : solr
```

In the synonym file we have a synonym defined as follows:

dawdle,waste time

Then in our data we have an entity with a name field "dawdle company".

Because of the synonym filter this gets analyzed to something like:

```
1 -dawdle- 2 -company- 3
1 -wasted- 2 -time- 3
```

With time and company in the same position. Then when performing a search for "wasted time" we get a hit in this entity. We would like the highlights to be "dawdle" since that is the equivalent synonym, but it seems elastic search sees this as a two hits since it matched "wasted" and "time" and it returns two highlights: "dawdle" and "company".

Is there a recommended way to solve these kind of issues where an unexpected word is returned in the highlights because it occupies the same position of a search term that was inserted because of a synonym?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @femtoRgon I am seeing the same behavior in latest Elasticsearch version - 1.7.0, Lucene version - 4.10.4.

Comment: @SergeyS can you provide your mapping for that specific field and the query you are using for highlighting?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Mapping - "contents":{"type":"string","store":true,"term_vector":"with_positions_offsets","index_analyzer":"analyzer_synonym","search_analyzer":"analyzer_search"}

Comment: Highlighting part of query - "highlight":{"pre_tags":["<em>"],"post_tags":["</em>"],"fragment_size":500000,"fields":{"contents":{"type":"plain"}}}

Answer (score 4):

@SergeyS the situation both you and @user2430530 has is perfectly described in this [section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html#_use_simple_contraction_for_phrase_queries) of the documentation.

And the suggestion there is to try and define a single term for each serie of synonyms not to get back that mix up of terms highlighted in the result.

Something like this:

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "synonym": {
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "filter": [
        "synonym"
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "synonym": {
      "type": "synonym",
      "synonyms": [
        "dawdle, waste time=>waste_time"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you'll get the desired result from ES:

```
        "highlight": {
           "text": [
              "some <em>dawdle</em> company"
           ]
        }
```

Comment: I know about this workaround. This is not suitable for me, because it has many other downsides, which are mentioned in the same article a little bit below. Any other ideas without using simple contraction and query-time synonyms? Please note that I am using query_string Query in the same time.

Comment: I have tested various highlighters (actually, all of them) and all gave the same output. At this point, I'd say "no" but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Also, since this comes from the official ES documentation, I'm inclined to believe this is the **only** way.

Comment: @SergeyS any way you could describe in more details your scenario and what it doesn't work? Maybe it can be done in a different way. For example, the downside mentioned in the documentation can be worked around it by using a sub-field with a different analyzer.

Comment: I cannot use query-time multi-word synonyms because of query_parser, because it will tokenize phrase before applying synonyms.

Comment: @SergeyS My stand is that there is no one-approach-good-for-all. As you saw in the docs, the first workaround is to use simple contraction, but not with query_string. So, obviously, some scenarios work, some not. You can't have both. It's difficult to offer an workaround at this point. I'd like to see your queries to see if we can replace `query_string` with something else. But, I imagine it's difficult to share this since you placed the bounty on a post opened by someone else and changing the initial post so much might not be accepted.